# http request php listener

Tags: java, php, json

I'm trying to make a php script that can listen to http request from [this java class](https://github.com/SKCraft/Launcher/blob/master/launcher/src/main/java/com/skcraft/launcher/util/HttpRequest.java), I tried to use $_POST but it seems that isn't working. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `echo file_get_contents("php://input");` to know what is exactly sent by your java class. `$_POST` will work only if the data is an urlencoded string. If your javaclass is sending json, you should read it like this: `$JSON = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);`

Comment: Thanks, now the php part is working perfectly, I'm still having issues whit the java part but I can solve it on my own!